# Update the value of JSON elements in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have table with following table structure:

```
create table instances(
                       id               bigint, 
                       createdate       timestamp, 
                       createdby        bigint, 
                       lastmodifieddate timestamp, 
                       lastmodifiedby   bigint, 
                       context          text
                       )
```

Field `context` contains a JSON data i.e.

```
insert into instances values 
(1, '2020-06-01 22:10:04', 20112,'2020-06-01 22:10:04',20112, 
    '{"id":1,"details":[{"binduserid":90182}]}')
```

I need to replace all values of JSON element `binduserid` with value 90182 using postgres query.

I have achieved this by using `REPLACE` function:

```
update instances 
   set context = replace(context, '"binduserid":90182','"binduserid":1000619')
```

Is there any other way to do this by using Postgres JSON Functions

Comment: Why are you storing json as `text` instead of `json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let's consider storing the column as JSON or JSONB those are already defined to hold the data properly and use in a productive manner such as no needed conversions among types like holding a DATE value in DATE format rather than a STRING.

In this case I consider `context` column in JSONB data type.

You can use `JSONB_SET()` function in order to get the desired result where the first argument(*target*) might be in array format through use of `JSONB_BUILD_ARRAY()` function with indexes (as `0` in `'{0,details}'` for this case ) to manipulate easily by the below DML Statement :

```
UPDATE instances
   SET context = 
          JSONB_SET(JSONB_BUILD_ARRAY(context), '{0,details}','[{"binduserid":1000619}]')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e8286131f0a6175eaa567e1e877e25c3)</kbd>